# Refresh chart without duplicating data

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a chart that duplicate when I refresh it.

In fact, I clear the chart with this code:

```
chrt.Series.Clear()
chrt.Titles.Clear()
```

Then I call again the chart function to display values in chart.

When I do that, It just duplicate palettes.

Code:

```
connection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password='';database= inventory_control")

        connection.Open()
        Dim cmdstring1 As String = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(quantity)) from inventory"
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT category, quantity from inventory"
        command = New MySqlCommand(cmdstring, connection)
        command1 = New MySqlCommand(cmdstring1, connection)

        Dim intResult As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery

        MsgBox(intResult)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        'Read data from column
        While reader.Read()
            strTosplit += reader("category") & " "
            strQty += reader("quantity") & ", "
        End While
        'Remove empty string from array
        Dim xValues() As String = strTosplit.Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(
            Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
                ).ToArray()
        Dim zValues() As String = strQty.Split(New Char() {","})


        ' Dim xValues() As String =  

        Dim yValues() As Integer = (From str In zValues
                                    Let isInt = Int32.TryParse(str, value)
                                    Where isInt
                                    Select Int32.Parse(str)).ToArray


        connection.Close()

        Dim seriesName As String = Nothing


        ' Note 1 : Clear chart before fill - VERY IMPORTANT and can generate exception if you are generating
        '          multiple charts in loop and have not included below lines !

        chrt.Series.Clear()
        chrt.Titles.Clear()

        ' Give unique Series Name
        seriesName = "Articles in Store"

        chrt.Series.Add(seriesName)

        ' Bind X and Y values
        chrt.Series(seriesName).Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues)


        chrt.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False


        ' If you want to show Chart Legends
        chrt.Legends(0).Enabled = True


        ' If you don't want to show data values and headings as label inside each Pie in chart
        chrt.Series(seriesName)("PieLabelStyle") = "Disabled"
        chrt.Series("Articles in Store").IsValueShownAsLabel = False

        ' If you want to show datavalues as label inside each Pie in chart
        chrt.Series("Articles in Store").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
```

Comment: You will need to step through the code to see how the chart is populated. From the details you have given its impossible for us to second guess why this is happening.

Comment: Where is strTosplit defined?